# Is deniable error-correction possible?

Tags: algorithm-design

This question came up as I tried to answer an earlier question I asked: [Cryptographic data structure: sparse array without membership test](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19244/cryptographic-data-structure-wanted-sparse-array-without-membership-test).  I still have not resolved that question to my satisfaction, but this question may be appreciated independently.

I want an error-correcting code that has the additional property that when encoding a string that cannot itself be feasibly distinguished from a random string, the encoding cannot be feasibly distinguished from a random string either.  So, for example, Alice could generate a random 1000 bit string, encode it using the algorithm to get a 2000 bit string, and send it over a noisy channel to Bob.  Bob could recover Alice's original 1000 bit string (even if there were many corrupted bits) but would have no way of knowing that Alice did not just send a random 2000 bit string.

I realize that "deniable" may not be the best word to use for this property since this word already has a different technical use in cryptography.  But I am not sure what to call the property.

Also, are there any tags I should be using besides "algorithm-design"?  For both my previous question and this one, I felt that there was no completely appropriate tag.

Comment: From my limited understanding error correction is $m | e$ where $e$ is some extra data used to correct up to a portion of $m$. Assuming $m$ is encrypted, and thus indistinguishable from a random string, what benefit is to be gained from making $e$ also indistinguishable? Unless the scheme is studied for its own merit.

Comment: "cannot feasibly be distinguished from a random string cannot feasibly be distinguished from a random string"?

Comment: @rath It is not required that the message itself be an initial segment of the code, though some codes have that property.  If you want a motivation, see my previous question.  That question came from thinking about a practical problem.

Comment: @Ricky If x looks random and y is the encoding of x then y looks random too.  Hopefully the Alice/Bob example makes it clearer?

Comment: @RickyDemer: you're parsing it wrong: "the encoding of a string (that cannot be distinguished from random) cannot be distinguished from random".  He's asking if the encoding can be made indistiguishable (and the answer is easy if Alice and Bob share a secret)

Comment: @poncho Great! Can you expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @poncho : $\:$ Oh yeah, that _could_ be non-simplifiable if there's no known way to efficient encode strings. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @gmr : $\:$ I doubt that poncho's parenthetical remark will help you, since your other question "would need the ECC to be indistinguishable (with high probability -- there can be some bit strings that are obviously not ECC codes) even to someone in possession of the key". $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that corrects some errors:

- Alice has a bitstring S that is indistinguishable from random that she wants Trent to know. (Perhaps it's actually a ciphertext that only Bob knows how to decrypt).
- Alice generates 5 fresh new random bit-strings pM, pN, pP, pQ, and pR just as long as the original random bitstring S.
- For each bit of S, Alice checks the the corresponding 5 bits of the random strings pM, pN, pP, pQ, and pR. If the majority of those 5 bits is the *same* as S, Alice keeps that bit the same, otherwise Alice flips all 5 bits, generating 5 modified versions of those random strings M, N, P, Q, and R.
- Alice sends M, N, P, Q, and R to Trent.
- For each bit of the messages M, N, P, Q, and R, Trent uses [5-modular redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/triple_modular_redundancy) -- the majority of the 5 bits -- to attempt to recover the string S.

Because pM, pN, pP, pQ, and pR are completely randomly generated, and S is indistinguishable from random, Trent is still unable to distinguish M, N, P, Q, and R from random bit-strings.

For any one bit-position, the 5 bits can be in any one of 32 possible patterns with equal probability.
If there is no bit error in some particular position, Trent always recovers the correct bit of S at that position.
Trent can *usually* correct any single-bit-flip error across a row of 5 bits.
(Given any 1 of the 5 bit positions ahead of time that will suffer a single-bit-flip error, 20 of the 32 possible patterns result in Trent recovering the correct bit of S, but the remaining 12 possible patterns would result in Trent decoding an erroneous bit).

I suspect there is a better encoding that allows Trent to *always* correct any single-bit-flip error.
Perhaps somehow forbidding the 12 vulnerable patterns, even though that allows statistical tests to conclude the collection of strings M, N, P, Q, and R are not completely random?

Comment: Thanks, this does show that some error correction is possible.  But arguably the hallmark of error-correcting codes is that for some transmission rate you can encode stuff with an arbitrarily low error rate, and I don't see any way to generalize your method to get that.

Comment: @gmr, you could always apply it recursively, though the data size grows fast.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Fujisaki-Okamoto CCA2-Security conversion. This is what you need.

In short, this is a conversion that makes the ciphertext of the McEliece encryption scheme (which is based on error correction codes) to be indistinguishable from random.

Comment: I looked up this conversion on the web.  As far as I can discern, it is a general method for takes (1) a public key cryptosystem that is secure against chosen plaintext attacks but not necessarily chosen ciphertext attacks and (2) a symmetric key cryptosystem that is secure against chosen ciphertext attacks and gives you (3) a public key cryptosystem secure against chosen ciphertext attacks.  I don't see the connection between this and my question.  The question does not involve encryption at all.

Comment: @gmr, I know your question has nothing to do with encryption scheme. The point is that this conversion makes a ciphertext indistinguishable from random. Now recall that the ciphertext of McEliece scheme is the encoding of the plaintext (with some errors), exactly as you described in your problem. In short, you just have to adapt the concept of McEliece+FujisakiOkamotoConversion to your context. Another good example of CCA2 secure conversion is the one proposed by Kobara-Imai. Take a look at this last one. It is completely focused on the McEliece scheme. (Y)

Comment: This idea looks really interesting, and I upvoted your answer, but I have not yet found time to really study the technologies the answer uses and convince myself that it works.  Nonetheless, I will ask a question.  Maybe this is obvious, but if Bob gets what is effectively a ciphertext, how can he unencode it without a key? Or if the key is made public, doesn't that break the indistinguishability from randomness property?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. The McEliece PK Enc. Scheme works as follows. Both priv. and pub. keys are descriptions of a single linear-code. The private description is a 'privileged' description which ables efficient error-correction. The public one just enables encoding (i.e. it can't correct errors). The idea of McEliece was to encode the plaintext and purposely add some errors. In other words, the 'challenge'of this cryptosystem is the ability of efficient correcting errors. But this scheme, as described above, has a problem. See below.

Comment: The problem of this scheme is that the encoded plaintext, even with some flipped bits, usually leak plaintext information. Here starts the job of a CCA2 secure conversion. It provably makes the encoded text indistinguishable from random. Thus anybody seeing your communication would ever imagine that a ciphertext is being transmitted. Now regarding the decrypted ciphertext (i.e. de plaintext), the indisnguishability property will hold as long as the plaintext is indistinguishable. In other words, if the plaintext is indistinguishable, then it will keep being indistinguishable after decryption.

Comment: I'm just repeating my last question, but isn't the indistinguishability from randomness predicated on the would-be distinguisher not knowing the private key?  But if I understand your first paragraph, it is the private key that Bob would need to read Alice's message.  The public key just lets him encode messages of his own, which is not something he needs to do.

Comment: @gmr Not sure if I get your question. I will explain how the protocol would act here in the hope you understand my reasoning. 
Alice wants to send a confidential message to Bob. Thus Alice gets Bob's public-key from some trust third-party authority, encrypts its message with this public-key and send the ciphertext (which is indist. from random) to Bob. Then Bob decrypts the ciphertext using its private-key. The end. Please let me know if you still have doubts on this scheme.

Comment: OK, the question you are answering is a little different from the one I was trying to ask.  I want anybody to be able to recover the message and no one to be able to tell whether there is a message to recover.  You divide the world into two kinds of people, those who can neither recover the message nor tell whether there is a message to recover and those that can do both.  A solution to my problem can be transformed into a solution to yours but not vice versa.

Comment: Also, can you clarify how the CCA2 secure conversion works and in particular why it doesn't destroy the error-correcting property?

Comment: Actually your question is confusing because it does not make any sense. Linear codes are vector subspaces. Any description of this linear vector space can encode your text. With high probability, a description picked at random will have absolutely no structure and thus cannot be used to introduce bias in the ciphertext. This implies that a plaintet with high entropy will be encoded to a ciphertext with high entropy, with high probability. That's all.

Comment: If you just McEliece encrypted, by not adding too many random errors, you can presumably retain some error correction.  I assume that is how the error correction is supposed to work.  According to Figure 2 in the Kobara-Imai paper, in the Fujisaki-Okamoto "simple" conversion the ciphertext is still the McEliece encryption of something, so that looks fine.  But they say that the simple conversion is broken, and the non-broken conversions they give in Figures 3 and 4 look like they won't have any error correction because they concatenate something that has not been ECC'd to the McEliece code.

Comment: McEliece scheme uses the error-correction problem to build up a public-key encryption scheme. It is not intended to correct any error arising from the transmission channel. These two things: (1) encryption and (2) error-correction with telecom purposes, are addressed in different layers of the communication protocol.

Comment: OK, it seems like we have had a gigantic misunderstanding.  As I said in my first response to you, my question does not involve encryption at all.  Not in any way.  Just error-correction.  Anyway, thanks for your time and sorry it was such a waste.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an error correcting code $C$ is simply a collection of codewords of a given length $n$ that meet some desired minimum (Hamming) distance properties.  Any tell-tale structure that is present is not intrinsic to the error-correcting properties, it's there in order to ease encoding and decoding and to allow you to prove that the desired properties exist.

Since $C$ can be arbitrarily chosen, there is no way to tell if a single word is a member.  If Trent sees a large number of messages (and let's assume he sees them before the noisy channel), he can see if the there is anything unusual about their distribution - that their minimum pairwise distance is larger than expected for that number of messages.  The larger the minimum distance between codewords, the more quickly he can conclude (with statistical certainty) that such a scheme is in use.

This can be fixed by changing codes for each message based upon some pre-arranged scheme.  Note that for any code $C$ the code $C_k = \{ c + k | c \in C \}$ is an error correcting code with the same power for any $k$.  You can probably use a construct analogous to CBC mode to make this secure.

Part of your question seems to propose that Trent knows $C$ but only sees the data after it has passed over the noisy channel.  His ability to detect if the error correcting code was used will depend on the channel.  At one extreme, if it never corrupts data, he'll always be able to tell whether the sent message is in $C$.  In general, this is going to depend on the balance of $d$, the error correcting ability of the code, and the noise properties of the channel.  Alice will want $d$ large enough to correct expected errors, but the larger it is the more distinguishing power Trent has.

Comment: Thanks, @bmm6o.  On "Since $C$ can be arbitrarily chosen, there is no way to tell if a single word is a member", are you thinking that the attacker Trent would not know what code is in use but the intended recipient Bob would?  Because that is not the setup.  No one other than the sender Alice knows anything anyone else doesn't.  On "he can see if there is anything unusual about their distribution", the question was about a single message, but even if we allow multiple messages, it isn't clear to me that this gives up information, so long as the number of messages is not astronomical,

Comment: especially if the code need not be optimal.  On "At one extreme, if it never corrupts data, he'll always be able to tell whether the sent message is in $C$", I think there is an ambiguity in the idea of "knowing $C$".  $C$ will be far too large to know by having a list of list members.  Also, a separate point is that it just isn't true that you need to know what code is in use to be able to recover encoded words; approximate knowledge of the code can suffice with high probability.

Comment: Given a set of words $W$ and the noise profile of the channel it's easy to calculate the probability that some received message $w'$ was originally broadcast as a word in $W$.  That seems too simple, but I don't see any other way to interpret your question if nothing is secret and there's only 1 message sent.

Comment: Let me say a number of independent things, some of which you may already know and/or may not matter to the argument you are making.  The sender (Alice) can have secrets.  The probability is only determined given a distribution over what was sent.  It is not required that the sender always encode the same word in the same way.  The calculation you describe will not necessarily be feasible.  The last comment I wrote to @otus may clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your deniability/indistinguishability definition requires a random piece of data and a error correcting piece of data to look the same to a decoder, because that seems like a requirement in the application you linked. In that case any error-correcting code that can fix all one bit errors is necessarily distinguishable from random data. Sketch of proof:

Suppose you have an indistinguishable ECC capable of correcting all one bit errors. Encode some message using it. That code and all the codes that differ from it by one bit must produce the same message when decoded. However, the same cannot be true for all the modified messages, or else the ECC is capable of correcting all two bit errors. Apply induction to show that it means it must correct n-bit errors, which is impossible in general. A random piece of data has a chance of being one of those "corrupted codes", so it can be distinguished by seeing if all the one bit changes get fixed or not.

A scheme such as that detailed in [David Cary's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19357/13625) is probably the best you can do.

Comment: The issue is whether you can partition the $n$ bit strings into a large number of classes in such a way that few strings have small Hamming distance from a string in a different class.  Maybe there is a simple combinatorial argument that this is impossible, but I can't see it.  If you don't know the answer, maybe I should just ask on Math Stack Exchange.  I'm basically 100% sure that the answer is known and the proof is simple.

Comment: @gmr, yes, perhaps you should ask on math.se. Intuitively it seems clear that the proportion of non-correctable strings it not negligible.